# Why are some complaints accompanied by affidavits by the Plaintiff parties verifying the complaint's accuracy?

Tags: civil

I assumed that the factual allegation in a complaint were always assumed true so an affidavit by the Plaintiff verifying the accuracy of the factual allegation would appear unnecessary, or? Why is this done?

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons to verify a complaint (i.e. to swear that its factual allegation are true).

**1. This is required for certain kinds of claims in certain jurisdictions as a matter of statute or court rule, which vary widely.**

For example, in Colorado, a "replevin claim" (i.e. a claim for expedited recovery of possession of specific tangible personal property) must be verified, and the object will be repossessed by force under court order if a timely response is not filed, often in a matter of a week or two, when the lack of a response could be due to reasons other than a lack of a good defense to the seizure.

Generally speaking, this is required when the relief requested is extraordinary relative to an ordinary lawsuit to collect an unpaid bill or recover damages from an injury in an accident, but requirements vary considerably from one jurisdiction to another.

Historically, at least, there have been jurisdictions in which all complaints must be verified, and there are other jurisdictions where it is almost never required.

**2. The lawyer wants to insulate himself from liability.**

A lawyer is required to exercise due diligence to confirm that the facts in documents filed with a court are true. Normally, a lawyer is entitled to simply rely on the fact that this lawyer's clients are telling the truth. But, if the client is sketchy, it is hard to independently confirm the facts, or the facts alleged seem extraordinary, the lawyer can be mostly insulated from liability for sanction for filing a complaint that lacks a factual basis by having a client swear to the fact under penalty of perjury.

**3. A motion for summary judgment is likely.**

In most U.S. jurisdictions, if a party defending a claim provides a factually detailed affidavit in support of a motion to dismiss a case because the facts alleged in the complaint are not true, the claim against that party will be dismissed unless the party bringing the claim files a response to the motion for summary judgment supported by a factually detailed affidavit disputing the facts alleged in the defending party's affidavit on material issues that creates a "disputed issue of fact" that must be resolved in an evidentiary hearing or trial by a judge or jury.

If the initial complaint contains factually detailed assertions in support of its allegations that are verified, i.e. sworn it as if by an affidavit, then that route to ending the case prematurely with a motion for summary judgment is largely thwarted. This can be a particularly valuable tactic for a plaintiff is the plaintiff may not be someone whom it is easy for the plaintiff's lawyer to contact on short notice.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, things in a complaint will be questioned or you would not be going to court.  There are different circumstances where an affidavit is used so I can't list every instance here, but most of the time when a complaint is filed, at least part of it is not already on the record and would therefore be like testimony being entered, where you are sworn before testifying.

My state, Illinois, even has laws regarding it. In Illinois when they cite that law or attach a separate affidavit, they are acknowledging they complied with that law. 
http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/documents/073500050K1-109.htm

Comment: The statute linked goes to how it is done, rather than when it must be done, permitting an unnotarized declaration under penalty of perjury rather than a notarized verification or affidavit.

Comment: The statute includes affidavits, "bill of particulars, answer to interrogatories, affidavit,".  As I said in the answer, it would be used when the complaint alleges something that is not solely a matter of law, is of record all already, or must be verified to be true for some other reason.

Comment: “Things in a complaint will be questioned...” You’ve misunderstood or are unaware of the concept OP was referencing. In determining whether a complaint will survive a motion to dismiss, the court looks at the facts alleged in the complaint and they are assumed to be true for this purpose. This doesn’t indicate the actual veracity of the allegations, but rather whether they are plausible (and thus survive the MTD).

Comment: @Putvi This is not what the Illinois statute that you cite means. Unverified complaints and answers alleging factual matters can be and routinely are filed in Illinois. It is simply saying that anything that would have had to have been sworn before a notary prior to the enactment of the statue can instead be signed under penalty of perjury without a notarization.

Comment: @A.fm. no one argued that either way. I said it is used when verifying things that may or may not be true.

Comment: @ohwilleke not to be rude to you, but in TEN YEARS of working for the sheriff here  in IL I have never seen an unverified complaint. It does not happen here.

Comment: @Putvi Even if Illinois law does have such a requirement, this statute doesn't create it. It says "Unless otherwise expressly provided by rule of the Supreme Court, whenever in this Code any . . . document or pleading filed in any court of this State is required or permitted to be verified, or made, sworn to or verified under oath, *such requirement or permission is hereby defined to include* a certification of such pleading, affidavit or other document under penalty of perjury as provided in this Section." This statute doesn't define what documents are required or permitted to be verified.

Comment: @ohwilleke you are extending what I said. No one said that law adds a requirement. I'm saying that the citing on affidavits complaints and the like references that law. The theory behind citing it is that you verify what you say to be true and it's not on record allready.

Comment: The main relevant IL statute is: "(735 ILCS 5/2-605) (from Ch. 110, par. 2-605): "Verification of pleadings. (a) Any pleading, although not required to be sworn to, may be verified by the oath of the party filing it or of any other person or persons having knowledge of the facts pleaded. . . . . If any pleading is so verified, every subsequent pleading must also be verified, unless verification is excused by the court. . . ." It is optional in an initial complaint or if excused by the court. People verify is for procedural advantage, not because it is required in a complaint alleging facts.

Comment: @ohwilleke that covers civil suits, but in IL the law I cited is cited on criminal cases, divorce, etc. It is what is commonly used for all cases.

Comment: @Putvi that statute is cited to claim the privilege of not using a notary. The statute relating to when it must or must not be verified probably isn't routinely cited in the pleading itself. I assume that there are parallel provisions to 735 ILCS 5/2-605 for divorce cases and criminal cases in different statutes.

Comment: @ohwilleke once more, I didn't say the statute saying when it must or must not be verified is stated on it.

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm telling you that there's not just one law covering every time you must of must not put an affidavit with your paperwork and that the law I cited documents why people put "I verify these things to be true" etc.

Comment: @Putvi I don't disagree that there is more than one law. But, the question as I read it  is asking why a particular document does or does not have to be verified, rather than what kind of wording constitutes a sufficient verification, which is what 735 ILCS 5/109 does.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100395/discussion-on-answer-by-putvi-why-are-some-complaints-accompanied-by-affidavits).